# Vernam cipher key file sincronization

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am working in VB 2010 on a one-time pad software.
The problem is the following. I have a txt file with many continous characters like this "KHKJHDKJDHAKHDAKHDAKHAKDHADHAKJDHASJDHA", i need to read a variable number of this characters and after replace it with a same number of dots (Ex. read four chars "KHKJ" replaced them with four dots "....HDKJDETCETC"). After this i will have to memorize the position of the last dot, in the txt key file, for a next read of the remaining keys. How to do it?

Thanks to info.de for the quick reply and my apologize for not having deepened my request. Let me explain better, my project is a Vernam chat and i need to have one single keys txt file that must remain synchronized in some way between broadcaster and receiver. When I send the message the key used must be deleted and who receives after decripting delete it too. 
The goal is synchronizing the two key files!

I thought something like this:

'READ PART

```
Using stream = File.OpenRead("c:\key.txt")
stream.Seek(v, SeekOrigin.Begin)  
Dim b = New Byte(a - 1) {} ' 
stream.Read(b, 0, a) 
Dim str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b)
txtPad.Text = str    ' portions of code read in txt for encodinh/decoding 
End Using
```

v = startup position for read in file key.txt

a= lenght of text in key.txt to be taken = lenght of text to encode

WRITE PART

```
Using stream = File.OpenWrite("c:\key.txt")
stream.Seek(v, SeekOrigin.Begin)
Dim b = New Byte(a - 1) {}
stream.Write(b, 0, 1)
End Using
```

But how can I overwrite (no delete) with dots taken characters using this code?
And above all what will be the next coordinates to repeat a subsequent encoding/decoding operation? (V changes constantly)

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site isn't a code writing service. But, sometimes one has luck and code is coming soon. So, for future questions give us what code you have already tried by yourself and a Problem description please.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    '//--- -----------------------------------------------
    '//--- KHKJHDKJDHAKHDAKHDAKHAKDHADHAKJDHASJDHA-line1#
    '//--- KHKJHDKJDHAKHDAKHDAKHAKDHADHAKJDHASJDHA-line2#

    Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath & "\TextFile1.txt")
    Dim iReplaceLength As Integer
    Dim sReplaceSubString As String

    For Each line As String In lines
      MessageBox.Show(line)

      sReplaceSubString = "KHKJ"
      iReplaceLength = sReplaceSubString.Length
      MessageBox.Show(line.Replace(sReplaceSubString.ToCharArray, New String("."c, iReplaceLength)))

      MessageBox.Show(line.Substring(iReplaceLength, line.Length - iReplaceLength))

    Next

  End Sub

End Class
```